# Creating a new column using substring and gregexpr in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a table in which one of the columns is a string like this: `aaaaaaa_bbbbbb_ccccc_1111111`

There are about 20000 rows and I need to create a new column with this substring for each row: `aaaaaaa_bbbbbb_ccccc`

After some research I found that using `"substring"` and `"gregexpr"` would work for me, and indeed it works fine when I use a command like this for each line (or if I pick some line):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table)){
    table$column[i] <- 
         substring(table$column[i], 1, (gregexpr("_", table$column[i])[[1]][3])-1)
}
```

However I'd like to use it without the loop:

`table$column <- substring(table$column, 1, (gregexpr("_", table$column)[[1]][3])-1)`

But in this case the new column gets substrings that doesn't match the pattern I want, sometimes they are correct, sometimes they have random lenght.

Does someone know what might be causing these weird results?

Comment: You can try `table$column <- sub("(.*)_\\d+", "\\1", table$column)`

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's unclear what's going on there.  Can you provide a small reproducible example that shows this behavior?  Otherwise, you might consider a different approach, like the one suggested by docendo discimus.

Comment: You should _not_ be assigning lists to data.frame columns.

Comment: @42

If I'm right, I'm not assigning lists to data.frame... the `gregexpr` returns a list with all pattern positions. So I'm using the a specific item of the list to remove just the part of the string I'm not interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like this :

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(seq(10), function(x) c(x,paste(paste(sapply(seq(3),function(i) paste(rep(letters[sample(seq(26),1)],7),collapse="")),collapse="_"),paste(rep(as.character(sample(seq(9),1)),7),collapse=""),sep="_")))))
colnames(df) <- c("id","column")
df
#    id                          column
# 1   1 wwwwwww_kkkkkkk_bbbbbbb_7777777
# 2   2 iiiiiii_wwwwwww_qqqqqqq_5555555
# 3   3 iiiiiii_vvvvvvv_bbbbbbb_1111111
# 4   4 hhhhhhh_xxxxxxx_rrrrrrr_4444444
# 5   5 sssssss_eeeeeee_eeeeeee_8888888
# 6   6 ooooooo_ddddddd_rrrrrrr_9999999
# 7   7 yyyyyyy_rrrrrrr_hhhhhhh_1111111
# 8   8 yyyyyyy_rrrrrrr_lllllll_4444444
# 9   9 ggggggg_ggggggg_iiiiiii_6666666
# 10 10 ccccccc_lllllll_jjjjjjj_2222222
```

And that you want something like this :

```
df
#    id                  column
# 1   1 wwwwwww_kkkkkkk_bbbbbbb
# 2   2 iiiiiii_wwwwwww_qqqqqqq
# 3   3 iiiiiii_vvvvvvv_bbbbbbb
# 4   4 hhhhhhh_xxxxxxx_rrrrrrr
# 5   5 sssssss_eeeeeee_eeeeeee
# 6   6 ooooooo_ddddddd_rrrrrrr
# 7   7 yyyyyyy_rrrrrrr_hhhhhhh
# 8   8 yyyyyyy_rrrrrrr_lllllll
# 9   9 ggggggg_ggggggg_iiiiiii
# 10 10 ccccccc_lllllll_jjjjjjj
```

You can simply use `sub`:

```
df$column <- sub("_[0-9]+","",df$column)
```

`sub` allows you to replace the first match of a pattern in a `character` vector. Besides, it is vectorized, which allows us to avoid an explicit loop. Here we use the fact that you want to remove the «`numeric`» part, but in case you just want to exclude the part after the last `_`, you could consider doing :

```
df$column <- sub("_[0-9a-z]+$","",df$column)
```

**EDIT** (to address comments) :

I don't see any way to avoid doing a loop using `gregexpr`.

If I wanted a one-liner no matter what, I would probably implement it like this :

```
df$column <- substring(df$column, sapply(gregexpr("_", df$column), function(i) i[1]+1), sapply(gregexpr("_", df$column), function(i) i[3]-1))
```

Alternatively, we can go on with `sub`. If you also want to remove the first part of your string, you process it twice :

```
df$column <- sub("^[0-9a-z]+_","",df$column)
df$column <- sub("_[0-9a-z]+$","",df$column)
```

And the job is done.

Finally, you could also consider using `strsplit` :

```
df$column <- sapply(df$column, function(x) paste(strsplit(x,"_")[[1]][2:3],collapse="_"))
```

(for the latter, make sure your column is `character` and not `factor`)

Comment: this is great, but I need also to remove the first part. In your exemple, for the first line I would have: 

`kkkkkkk_bbbbbbb`

It would help if I had a list with all patter positions, as in  `gregexpr`. I'll try to adapt your code. Thank you!

Comment: the last part can be anything... not necessarily `numeric`

Comment: The first code of the EDIT works perfectly! I didn't know I could use `function(i)` this way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yay !! :-D Then if it solves your problem, maybe you could accept the answer ? ;-)